# IO multiplexing in Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, io, aio

Is there something like the [sendfile](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile)-syscall that works with multiple target file descriptors (i.e. instead of copying from one FD to another FD, it could should copy to, say, 4 FDs)?

I know that when talking about asynchronous IO, this is known as gather/scatter, but I could not find anything in the Linux AIO documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of anything.  I think the closest you are going to get to this is, assuming you are dealing with pipes, is to fashion something out of [tee(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/tee), [vmsplice(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vmsplice) and [splice(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice).

Comment: Thanks, splice looks like the right thing, since I mainly care about preventing multiple kernel-to-userspace copies